# Change the indent structure of a paragraph

Tags: indentation

Is there way to change the indent structure of a specific paragraph like shown in the picture?

All the paragraphs begin with indent and no indent afterwards but the third paragraph begins with no indent and then the new lines are indented.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single paragraph not containing lists or other list based objects such as `enumerate` or `center`, you can use the primitives `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{reversepar}[1][\parindent]
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}\hangindent=#1\hangafter=1\parindent=0pt\relax}
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{reversepar}
\lipsum[4]
\end{reversepar}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the amount of hanging indentation with

```
\begin{reversepar}[<dimen>]
```

Answer (score 4):

How about a `enumitem`-based solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{weirdparagraph}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[weirdparagraph]{
  label=,
  leftmargin=2.5em,
  itemindent=-\leftmargin,
  listparindent=-\leftmargin,
  partopsep=0pt,
  topsep=0pt,
  itemsep=0pt,
  parsep=\parskip
}

\newcommand\test{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
  facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
  mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
  augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.%
}

\setlength\parindent{3.5em}
\setlength\parskip{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}
\test

\test

\begin{weirdparagraph}
\item \test\par\test
\end{weirdparagraph}

\test
\end{document}
```

[image: enumitem]

Answer (score 0):

The `hanging` package also does it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, hanging}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \hangpara{2em}{1}\lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

as:

[image]